# cuda kernel for add(a,b,c) using texture objects for a & b - works correctly for 'increment operation' add(a,b,a)?

Tags: cuda, textures

I want to implement a cuda function 'add(a,b,c)' for adding (component-wise) two one-channel floating-point images 'a' and 'b' together and storing the result in the floating-point image 'c'. So 'c = a + b'.
The function will be implemented by first binding texture objects 'aTex' and 'bTex' to the pitch-linear images 'a' and 'b', and then accessing the image 'a' and 'b' inside the kernel *only* via the texture objects 'aTex' and 'bTex'. The sum is stored in 'c' via a simple write to global memory. 
What happens now if I call the function for *incrementing* 'a' by 'b' - so I call 'add(a,b,a)' ? Because now, the image 'a' is used in the kernel on two places - from 'a' I read in the value via the texture object 'aTex', and I also *store* values in 'a' via the write to global memory. Is it possible that this usage of the 'add' function leads to incorrect results ?

Comment: Texture objects are read only, if you want to be able to write to them, use surface objects instead.

Comment: I know, but in this specific use-case of the routine I read from 'a' via texture object, and write to 'a' via global memory. I just want to know whether the kernel - called in that way - will function correctly.

Comment: The texture cache is not coherent. Therefore, a global memory write to underlying storage for a particular location may or may not be reflected by a subsequent texture access to the same location. If, after the update by global memory write, a particular location is never read via the texture path inside the same kernel (i.e. no read-after-write hazard), everything should work just fine. The next kernel will see the updated global memory, and start with a cleared texture cache.

Comment: That fine. That means for all arithmetic operations which operate pixel-wise my routine will work fine. Of course all sort of convolutions / morphological operations, where the output pixel depends on more than one input pixel, I will be out of luck.

Comment: @njuffa Could you please convert your comment to an answer? I would upvote.

Comment: @JackOLantern Thanks for the endorsement. I have expanded my comment into an answer.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks. Your answers are always illuminating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPU's texture is not coherent. This means that a global memory write to a particular location of the global memory underlying a texture may or may not be reflected during a subsequent texture access to that same location. So there is a read-after-write hazard in such a scenario.

If, however, the code performs a global memory write to a particular location of the global memory underlying a texture, *and that location subsequently is never read from via the texture* during the lifetime of the kernel, there is no read-after-write hazard, and the code will behave as expected: The updated data in global memory can be accessed by a subsequent kernel in any manner desired, including texture access, as the texture cache is cleared upon a kernel launch.

I have personally used this approach to speed up in-place operations with small strides as the texture read path provided higher load performance. An example would be the BLAS-1 operation [D|S|Z|C]SCAL in CUBLAS, which scales each array element by a scalar.